# error php Undefined offset: 2-3-4 etc

Tags: php

i need some help..hope you guys can help me.this is my code.

```
Error Message: Undefined offset: 2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-10-11-12-13-14-15-16-17-18
Errore durante l'accesso alla banca dati:
Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
{SC_DB_ERROR_INI}View SQL{SC_DB_ERROR_MID}INSERT INTO magazzinoonline (TRCDMG,TRCDMA,TRARFO,TRDESC,TRUNMI,TRCONF,TRDISP,TROBSO,TRNOMT,TRMULT,TRPREZ,TRLIST,TRLIB1,TRLIB2,TRLIB3,TRLIB4,TRLIB5,TRLIB6,TRDTTR) VALUES('DM13MI80611207012 SCOTCH SUPER 33 + 19X20X0','18 NASTRO PVC PC 00001000000101 0000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 161006','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','',1476815766){SC_DB_ERROR_CLS}Close{SC_DB_ERROR_END}
```

```
//percorso
$path = $this->Ini->path_doc;

//percorso assoluto
$prova = $path . '/' . {prova};

 // apertura file
 $fr=fopen($prova,'r') or die("Impossibile aprire il file in lettura!");
 $sep=","; // separatore dei dati
 $riga=""; // azzeramento riga

 while(!feof($fr)){ // lettura file fino alla fine
 $riga=fgets($fr); // legge tutta la riga
 if(strlen($riga)>1){
 $riga=trim($riga); // elimino gli spazi all'inizio e alla fine
 $riga=ereg_replace("'","\'",$riga); // cambio i ' in \'
 $arrayriga=explode($sep,$riga); // metto i dati della riga in un array divisi col separatore

 $num_elementi=count($arrayriga); // numero di elementi nell'array 

 // query di inserimento
 if($num_elementi==2 && strlen($arrayriga[0])>0){
 $data=time(); // data attuale in formato linux

$query1="INSERT INTO magazzinoonline (TRCDMG,TRCDMA,TRARFO,TRDESC,TRUNMI,TRCONF,TRDISP,TROBSO,TRNOMT,TRMULT,TRPREZ,TRLIST,TRLIB1,TRLIB2,TRLIB3,TRLIB4,TRLIB5,TRLIB6,TRDTTR) VALUES('$arrayriga[0]','$arrayriga[1]','$arrayriga[2]','$arrayriga[3]','$arrayriga[4]','$arrayriga[5]','$arrayriga[6]','$arrayriga[7]','$arrayriga[8]','$arrayriga[9]','$arrayriga[10]','$arrayriga[11]','$arrayriga[12]','$arrayriga[13]','$arrayriga[14]','$arrayriga[15]','$arrayriga[16]','$arrayriga[17]','$arrayriga[18]',$data)";
sc_exec_sql($query1);

}
}
$arrayriga=array_slice($arrayriga,0,0); // azzero per il prossimo inserimento
$riga=""; // azzero per il prossimo inserimento
}
```

Comment: `ereg` has been deprecated since before the dinosaurs roamed the earth. You should **NOT** be using anything ereg related in any code.

Answer (score 0):

Look at what you're doing:

```
if($num_elementi==2 && strlen($arrayriga[0])>0){
        ^^^^
```

run the query only if there's 2 elements in the array, but then your query tries to access **19** values in that array, which you already confirmed only has **2**:

```
   $query1="INSERT[..snip...]'$arrayriga[18]',$data)";
                                         ^---
```

How can an array with only 2 elements have indexes 0->18?